# Xcode Swift/PHP/SQL upload multiple images failed

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am learning "posting images to server", but when I tried the multiple images uploading, it always failed with reporting(JSON error, from my Xcode alert on iOS devices), it seems error is in the PHP side? But I am new, so anyone can help me to find any solution.
Xcode:

1. httpBody function

   func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String : Any]?,boundary: String) -> NSData {
   let body = NSMutableData()

   ```
    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
    }

    for image in images {
        let filename = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpg"
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
        let lineOne = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
        body.append(lineOne.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
        let lineTwo = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n"
        body.append(lineTwo.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
        let lineThree = "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n"
        body.append(lineThree.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
        body.append(imageData!)
        let lineFive = "\r\n"
        body.append(lineFive.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    }

    let lineSix = "--" + boundary + "--\r\n"
    body.append(lineSix.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    return body
   ```

   }

2. http request function

   ```
    func createRequest(parameters: [String : Any] , url : URL) -> URLRequest {

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: parameters, boundary: boundary) as Data

    return request
   ```

   }
3. multi images upload functions
   func uploadPostWithMultipleImages() {

   ```
    guard let id = currentUser?["id"], let text = postTextView.text else {
        return
    }

    // declaring keys and values to be sent to the server
    let parameters = ["user_id": id, "text": text, "files": images]

    // declaring URL and request
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/projectExample/uploadPostMultipleImages.php")!

    let request = createRequest(parameters: parameters, url: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // if error
            if error != nil {
                Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                return
            }

            // access data / json
            do {

                // safe mode of accessing received data from the server
                guard let data = data else {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

                // converting data to JSON
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                // safe mode of accessing / casting JSON
                guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                    return
                }

                // if post is uploaded successfully -> come back to HomeVC, else -> show error message
                if parsedJSON["status"] as! String == "200" {

                    // post notification in order to update the posts of the user in other viewControllers
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "uploadPost"), object: nil)

                    // comeback
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Error", message: parsedJSON["message"] as! String, in: self)
                    return
                }

                // error while accessing data / json
            } catch {
                Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                return
            }
        }

    }.resume()
   ```

   }
4. PHP upload code

   ```
    // generating absolute path to the folder for every user with his unique id
   ```

   $folder = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectExample/posts/' . $user_id;

   // creating fodler if it doesn't exist
   if (!file_exists($folder)) {
   mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
   } else {
   $return['folder_message'] = 'Could not create a directory';
   }

   ```
    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key =>$value) {

    $file = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    // path to the file. Full path of the file
    $path = $folder . '/' . basename($file); 

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path)) {
    // creating URL link to the image uploaded
    $pictures .= 'http://localhost/projectExample/posts/' . $user_id . '/' . $file. " ";
    $return['pictures'] = $pictures;
    }
   ```

   }//foreach

// Insert details into database
$result = $access->insertPost($user_id, $text, $pictures);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your swift code and upload images successfully, so I am sure it's your PHP code that has some error. please make sure that you have return a json that is correctly-formatted like :

```
echo '{"code" : 200}'
```

Comment: I also posted the PHP code here, would you please help me have a look. In my knowledge, I typed, $return['pictures'] = $pictures;

Comment: I can't know what your PHP code returns. plz let me know this code "URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in" , what  is print(data)?

Comment: Haha, I resolved, I spent several days! Because my knowledge is too narrow. My issue is inside my swift code "multipart/form data section", the name I defined as "files", then "files" only can represent a single file, if want to send an array to PHP, then the name "files[]" is needed.